# Como fazer combinações sem usar o itertools em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho o seguinte código para gerar as combinações possíveis da loteria (mega-sena, por exemplo):

```
from itertools import combinations

sequencia = combinations(range(1,61), 6)

for teste in sequencia:

  print(teste)
```

Minha dúvida é:
Tem como fazer esse mesmo código acima sem usar a biblioteca de combinações mas de uma forma fácil para entendimento sem entrar em conteúdos mais avançados classes / objetos?

Comment: Amigo, não sei se entendi exatamente o que tu queres fazer... Uma opção para não usar as funcionalidades de uma biblioteca seria tu mesmo implementares o que ela faz. Tu já tentaste isso?

Comment: Sim, apenas com laços de repetição você consegue fazer as mesmas combinações. Inclusive, na própria documentação da função [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) há um código equivalente que você pode usar como base.

Answer (score 1):

Se você olhar a documentação da função [itertools.combinations(iterable, r)](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), está escrito que a função é aproximadamente equivalente a:

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Então sim é possível fazer combinações em python sem o uso do módulo itertools.